# Privileges to select any table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, permissions, select, oracle-12c

I'm using a Oracle database client application that connects to 1521 port to do "select" commands over every table in a Oracle db 12.1.

I told dba to create this role with these commands:

create role G_CLASSIFIER

```
grant CONNECT to G_CLASSIFIER
grant select any table to G_CLASSIFIER
grant select any dictionary to G_CLASSIFIER
```

After that, i told dba to create a new user with that role:

```
GRANT g_classifier to dbuser
```

However, "dbuser" doesn't access some schemas with those privileges. What i don't know if this is a privileges issue or not.

Should "dbuser" be able to access every table of every schema in the database or it depends of some db configuration? Am i missing something?

If the user should have access to every table and schema, this is not a db issue.

I know nothing about database administration nor that Oracle database so i will be very grateful if you could help me with this Oracle dubt.

Comment: What does "doesn't access some schemas" mean?  Are you getting errors running a `select`?  If so, what errors?  Are the problematic statements in a definer's rights stored procedure?  An invoker's rights stored procedure?  A stand alone SQL statement?

Comment: @JustinCave Thank you for your response. The application is not returning any error, that is why i woud like to know if a user needs more privileges that the two grants i talked about to be able to select any table across the Oracle database. If yes, this is a db privileges error. In some other way, i need to check the application (even i don't see errors). I can't give you any information about app since it is not mine neither opensource, so i don't know more than what i talked about.

Comment: @JustinCave i mean, the only thing i know is the app didn't get the data of some tables in some schemas. So, there is an app error o there is an issue with privileges at db level. I didn't find an app error, so i would like to know about these privileges.

Comment: Well, that makes it a bit hard to guess at the problem.  In theory, the application could be running code inside a definer's rights stored procedure in which case privileges granted through a role are not visible.  You could try granting the privileges directly to the user rather than through a role.  But I'd guess that the database privileges are fine.

Comment: _"I know nothing about database administration nor that Oracle database"_  And yet you are directing your DBA as to what roles and privileges need to be configured??  Perhaps you should be asking your DBA what is wrong.  As it stands you are asking strangers to debug code that they cannot see.   _"The application is not returning any error"_  Then either the issue is not with privileges, or the app is swallowing the error.